# I want to use @Html.Raw(string), (where string contains a complete html webpage) and show multiple webpages in Card format side-by-side on same page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Below is the css and Html for the multiple card elements within a webpage and each card element contains a webpage, but this is not working for me. When I am trying to put texts at the place of webpage inside each card then its working fine.
I need the same layout as discussed above.

```css
.container{
    background-color:bisque;
    position:relative;
}
.container-2{
    width: 95%;
    background-color:black;
    padding: 20px;
    color:white;
}
.card-body {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}
.card-text{
    background-color:black;
}
.row {
    margin:0px -5px ;
}
column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* this adds the "card" effect */
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Asset> asset in assets)
     {
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card" style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll; width: 18rem; height: 300px; ">
              <div class="card-body" style="background-color:black">
                <h5 class="card-title" style="border:solid">@x.Value.title</h5>
                       <p class="card-text" style="color:whitesmoke">@Html.Raw("<!DOCTYPE html>"+"<html>" + "<head>" + x.Value.head + "</head>" + "<body>" + x.Value.body + "</body>" + "</html>");
                        </p>    
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       }
</div>
```

Here x is a `List<Dictionary<key,value>>` containing multiple data.

Comment: Hello did you tried the solution provided? let us know your feedback.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the solution and that worked for me. Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome and glad to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this is not working for me. When I am trying to put texts at the place of webpage inside each card then its working fine

Let's begin with this concern, because you are using Bootstrap’s card
component which has its own CSS. If you want to implement your custom CSS you have two ways: either modify Bootstrap’s CSS file, which is not recommended, or define your custom CSS file and then use that. The way you are trying will not work this way.

If I were you then might be solve this issue in following manner:

Web Site Dynamic Content From Backend:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult BindDynamicContentToHtmlCard()
{
   
   
    var convertedHtmlBodyList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var convertedHtmlBody = "";
        sb.Append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.Append("<head>");
        sb.Append("</head>");

        sb.Append("<body>");
        sb.Append("<h5 class='card - title' style='border: solid'><strong>TEST WEB SITE "+ i + " </strong></h5>");
        sb.Append("<p>Simplest solution of the dynamic card generation.</p>");
        sb.Append("<p>This is how you can generate dynamic Card</p>");
        sb.Append("<p><strong style='color: red'>Note:</strong> For more details please check details: <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71167733/i-want-to-use-html-rawstring-where-string-contains-a-complete-html-webpage'>Details</a></p>");
        sb.Append("</body>");
        sb.Append("</html>");
        convertedHtmlBody = sb.ToString();
        convertedHtmlBodyList.Add(convertedHtmlBody);
    }
   

    ViewBag.bindToHtmlInView = convertedHtmlBodyList;
    return View(); ;
}
```

Card HTML:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "BindDynamicToHtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.bindToHtmlInView)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card" style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <div class="card-body" style="background-color:white">
                        <p class="card-text" style="color:whitesmoke">
                            @Html.Raw(item)
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Card Output:

[image]

This is how you can get the card element without much CSS modification.