# Not able to read string value from cshtml.cs page in .cshtml page in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to ASP.NET Core 6.0 and I am facing an issue while reading a value from `.cshtml.cs` file in `.cshtml` page.

I have tried to use the `[BindProperty]` attribute and also tried to bind value in `ViewData`.

Basically, I have created an HTML Table and bound it to a string value. Please find below the sample code that I tried.

`cshtml.cs` code:

```
[BindProperty]
public string HTMLRep { get; set; }

HTMLRep = reportHTML; //reportHTML has the HTML Table in the post ActionMethod
```

I also tried

```
ViewData["HTML"] = reportHTML
```

`.cshtml` markup:

```
@{
    var val = ViewData["HTML"];
}

<panel>
   @Model.HTMLRep 
   //Also tried - 
   @val
<panel>
```

Any help on this will be very useful. Thank you

Comment: No the panel element comes blank....the table structure does not show. the ViewData and var element both are null.

Comment: I dont have any thing in the OnGet method...I have the logic written in the Post Method....You can use Div instead of Panel does not matter....I am not able retrieve the value of the string in the cshtml page....that is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello did you tried the solution provided? Is there anything else that you required assistance on it?

Comment: Hello,Yes the issue got resolved. I did create a Get Method and through ajax call I was able to read the value and process it in the success method.
Thank you for the help evryone.

Comment: If the answer was helpful you could accept it by right clicking beside your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you try to use HTML text for output it encodes it. So you have to write like following:

```
<panel>
   @Html.Raw(Model.HTMLRep)
<panel>
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: I have tried this but its not working. I am not sure but I think when the page is loading again the value goes null at that point of time. Just my thought.

Comment: When the page loads on the browser, the OnGet method is called, but you said you have the code inside OnPost. OnPost is called when you submit a form. Do you have a form in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If I would you then might be solve this issue in following manner.

Web Site Dynamic Content From Backend:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult BindDynamicContentToHtmlCard()
{
   
   
    var convertedHtmlBodyList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var convertedHtmlBody = "";
        sb.Append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.Append("<head>");
        sb.Append("</head>");

        sb.Append("<body>");
        sb.Append("<h5 class='card - title' style='border: solid'><strong>TEST WEB SITE "+ i + " </strong></h5>");
        sb.Append("<p>Simplest solution of the dynamic card generation.</p>");
        sb.Append("<p>This is how you can generate dynamic Card</p>");
        sb.Append("<p><strong style='color: red'>Note:</strong> For more details please check details: <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71167733/i-want-to-use-html-rawstring-where-string-contains-a-complete-html-webpage'>Details</a></p>");
        sb.Append("</body>");
        sb.Append("</html>");
        convertedHtmlBody = sb.ToString();
        convertedHtmlBodyList.Add(convertedHtmlBody);
    }
   

    ViewBag.bindToHtmlInView = convertedHtmlBodyList;
    return View(); ;
}
```

Panel HTML:

```cs
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "BindDynamicToHtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.bindToHtmlInView)
        {
            <panel>
                    @Html.Raw(item)
            </panel>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Panel Output:

[image]

Here you can get the panel element.